# LINQ query to filter list by object property with multiple checks

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List` of objects; I want to filter this list by the first letter in a string property of the objects.

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public MyObject(){}
}
```

I am using a LINQ query:

```
List<MyObject> myList = FillList();

myList = myList.Where(p => p.Name[0] != "A").ToList();
```

My problem is that the first letter of `Name` may be preceded by whitespace. Three examples of `Name` property:

```
0 1 2 3 4
N A M E
  N A M E
    N A M
```

Rather than removing all whitespace from `Name`, can this be done with LINQ?

Comment: Just trim the string...

Comment: how is that compiling.It should give an error like: `Cannot apply operator == to operands of type 'char' and 'string'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TrimStart`, note that strings are immutable so you won't modify the original string.

```
myList = myList
    .Where(p => !p.Name.TrimStart().StartsWith("A")).ToList();
```

I'm using `StartsWith` because it's clear and also handles the case of an empty string.

Comment: missing a ")" before .ToList

Answer (score 4):

You can use `TrimStart` and temporarily remove whitespaces in the begining of your `Name` and check for the first letter

```
myList = myList.Where(p => p.Name.TrimStart(' ')[0] != 'A').ToList();
```

By the way you need to use `'A'` becasue `Name[0]` is a `char` not a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can! Use multiple checks in your `.Where()` clause, a la

```
p.Name[0] != 'A' && p.Name[1] != 'A'...
```

Or, more simply, use `string.Trim()` to remove the trails G spaces:

```
.Where(p => p.Name.ToString().Trim().StartsWith('A')) `
```